# What does "<<-" mean in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

For example:

```
code = <<-EOH
    bundle install
    bundle exec unicorn -c /etc/unicorn.cfg -D
EOH
```

What does this code do? What is `<<-` called?

Comment: Symbolhound is one way to search for syntax that google can't handle.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It's called heredoc. An easy way to define multiline strings which may include single or double quotes without needing to escape them.

See more [here](http://blog.jayfields.com/2006/12/ruby-multiline-strings-here-doc-or.html), for example.

Often you use heredocs to define large chunks of code. [Some](http://macromates.com/) editors know about this and can highlight syntax for you there (if you specify language). Look:

[image: strings vs heredocs]

Comment: I like the syntax highlighting and learnt today that also first time.

Answer (score 8):

There is also a newer HEREDOC syntax for Ruby `<<~END` that more closely resembles what you would typically see in most shells and other languages with the `~` instead of the `-` to tell Ruby to strip the leading whitespace to match the least indented line in the block.

https://infinum.co/the-capsized-eight/multiline-strings-ruby-2-3-0-the-squiggly-heredoc

Comment: Oh, missed this one.

Answer (score 4):

Looks to me like heredoc. The `-` allows the ending delimiter to ignore whitespace before it.

A simple Google Search gave me [this](http://rubyquicktips.com/post/4438542511/heredoc-and-indent).

Comment: Heredocs *would* be a pain to google. The concept and implementation are both weird if you've never encountered them before.

Comment: I had never heard of heredoc so google was fruitless. Sometimes its difficult to put names to unknown symbols

Comment: A `<<-END` in bash/shell will strip the preceding whitespace, but in Ruby it isn't so simple, see my answer with the changes in 2.3.x that brought a bit of feature parity while requiring a new syntax.