# Difference between puts and MESSAGE?

Tags: ruby

What is the difference between using `MESSAGE` and tags for the last string?

```
user = ARGV.first
prompt = '>  '

puts "Hi #{user}, im the #{$0} script."
puts "I'd like to ask you a few questions."
puts "Do you like me #{user}?"
print prompt
likes = STDIN.gets.chomp()

puts "Where do you live #{user}?"
print prompt
lives = STDIN.gets.chomp()

puts "What kind of computer do u have?"
print prompt
computer = STDIN.gets.chomp()

puts <<MESSAGE
"Alright, so you said #{likes} about liking me. You live in #{lives}. Not sure where it is.
And you have a #{computer} computer, which is nice." 
MESSAGE
```

Comment: @JoshuaCheek: maybe he's referring to the `<<` in `<<MESSAGE`? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you see is something called [here-docs](http://blog.jayfields.com/2006/12/ruby-multiline-strings-here-doc-or.html). It's a convenient way to have multiline strings without having to escape quotes. Besides this, they are just regular strings.

Some editors may offer additional features. See [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10561197/125816) about this.