# writing HTML in ruby

Tags: html, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does “<<-” mean in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10561177/what-does-mean-in-ruby)

I saw this in devise_helper.rb

```
html = <<-HTML
<div> ... </div>
HTML

html.html_safe
```

what is this `<<-HTML .. HTML` notation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<<` is the [heredoc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/syntax.html#here_doc) syntax. The minus (`-`) removes all whitespace before the end marker (`HTML`).

Answer (score 3):

It's called [heredoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Ruby).

The variable will be ended at the `HTML` counterpart. But you can write any string to there.