# Ruby escape double quotes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Can someone help me with escaping double quotes

```
 iframe_name = page.execute_script "$('#card-element').find('[name*="__privateStripeFrame"').first().attr('name')"
```

tried with

```
 iframe_name = page.execute_script "$('#card-element').find('[name*=%Q[__privateStripeFrame]').first().attr('name')"
```

and

```
 iframe_name = page.execute_script "$('#card-element').find('[name*=\"__privateStripeFrame\"').first().attr('name')"
```

but got

```
TypeError (TypeError)
```

Comment: Last option works just fine

```2.4.1 :002 > "$('#card-element').find('[name*=\"__privateStripeFrame\"').first().attr('name')"
 => "$('#card-element').find('[name*=\"__privateStripeFrame\"').first().attr('name')" ```

Make sure you passing correct argument(s)

Comment: could be error in iframe_name =  part

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Escaping single and double qoutes from a string in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6705982/escaping-single-and-double-qoutes-from-a-string-in-ruby)

Comment: @vladimirProp please [be nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice).

Comment: problem was in something else take a look on my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use heredoc, it even reads better:

```
iframe_name = page.execute_script <<JS
  $('#card-element').find('[name*="__privateStripeFrame"]').first().attr('name')
JS
```

Comment: Also some editors might use the heredoc delimiters to infer [what syntax highlighter to use for the string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10561197/125816)!

Comment: @SergioTulentsev indeed.

Comment: problem was in something else take a look at my answer

Answer (score 1):

https://blog.appsignal.com/2016/12/21/ruby-magic-escaping-in-ruby.html

In Ruby you escape double quotes with the backslash character.

```
"foo\"bar\"" => 'foo"bar"'
```

Comment: problem was in something else look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys problem was in

```
page.execute_script
```

with this method TypeError is return

try to use

```
 page.evaluate_script
```

in order to store returned value

```
frame_name = page.evaluate_script("$('#card-element').find('[name*=\"__privateStripeFrame\"]').first().attr('name')")
```